# Image cliping is not working on the node canvas

Tags: javascript, node-canvas

I am trying to draw an uploaded image on a frame image which is a tilted frame image already saved on the server using node canvas.

The issue I am facing right now is the clipping functionality for the uploaded image from top and bottom to show it inside the frame properly adjusted is not working.

The code I am trying right now is:

```
const responseFileName = `${Date.now()}.png`;
const frameImageMetadata = await sharp(frames[i]).metadata();

const canvas = createCanvas(
  frameImageMetadata.width,
  frameImageMetadata.height
);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

const [frameImage, customImage] = await Promise.all([
  loadImage(frames[i]),
  loadImage(userUploadedImage),
]);

const frameWidth = frameImage.width;
const frameHeight = frameImage.height;

ctx.drawImage(frameImage, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);

// Set the size for the custom image (you may adjust these dimensions)
const customWidth = frameWidth * 0.92; // 80% of frame width
const customHeight = frameHeight * 0.95; // 80% of frame height

const tempCanvas = createCanvas(customWidth, customHeight);

const tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
tempCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
tempCtx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
tempCtx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

// Draw the custom image
tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);

// Define the diagonal shape parameters
ctx.rect(50, 20, 200, 120);
ctx.stroke();
tempCtx.clip();

const tempResponseFileName = `${Date.now()}.png`;

const tempGeneratedFile = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "public",
  "generated-images",
  tempResponseFileName
);

const tempOutput = fs.createWriteStream(tempGeneratedFile);
const tempStream = tempCanvas.createPNGStream({ compressionLevel: 0 });

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  tempStream.pipe(tempOutput);
  tempOutput.on("finish", resolve);
  tempOutput.on("error", reject);
});

// Draw the clipped custom image
ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 51, 25);

const generatedFile = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "public",
  "generated-images",
  responseFileName
);
const output = fs.createWriteStream(generatedFile);
const stream = canvas.createPNGStream({ compressionLevel: 0 });

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  stream.pipe(output);
  output.on("finish", resolve);
  output.on("error", reject);
});

images.push(`generated-images/${responseFileName}`);`
```

The frame image that I am using is:

[image: frame image]

Comment: `tempCtx.clip();` is the last operation on `tempCtx`. As you carefully checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) you probably just forgot that clipping affects the operations happening *after* the `clip()` call.

Comment: // Draw the custom image
tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);
tempCtx.clip();
// Define the diagonal shape parameters
tempCtx.rect(50, 20, 200, 120);
tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);

tried above code and still not working

// Draw the custom image
    tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);
    tempCtx.clip();
    // Define the diagonal shape parameters
    tempCtx.rect(50, 20, 200, 120);
    
this is also not working

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log` the code to see if `customWidth` and `customHeight` are being passed to the `clip()` function in the correct way.
Also `clip()` alone does not have any effect.
the image needs to be followed by a new drawing function after you called `tempCtx.clip();`
`tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);`

try this code that make you redraw after the clip:

```
/* rest of the code */

const tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
tempCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
tempCtx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
tempCtx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

// Draw the custom image
tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);

// Define the diagonal shape parameters
tempCtx.rect(50, 20, 200, 120);  // Define the shape on tempCtx instead of ctx
tempCtx.clip();  // Apply the clipping on tempCtx

tempCtx.drawImage(customImage, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);  // add this line

/* rest of the code */
```

since it is difficult to grasp these concept let's try something simpler:

```
// Create a canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Get the context
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an image
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://example.com/image.png';
img.onload = function() {
  // Draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

  // Define the clipping region
  ctx.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.clip();

  // Draw the image again to apply the clipping
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
};
```

1. image is loaded and drawn onto a canvas
2. a clipping region is defined using `ctx.rect()`, and the `clip()` function is called to apply the clipping
3. the image is drawn again in the clipped region

Comment: this is not working, can you provide a working fiddle for this?? Also, sorry for this but i am new to canvas so, can you tell me how can i `console.log` to check if `customWidth` and `customHeight` are being passed to the clip() function

Comment: for starting to debug press F12 in any browser and you will have the console. also i added additional information to my previous answer